# Not able to save multiple records with Realm

Tags: xcode, realm, nstableview

### Goals

I'm trying to update a few records and delete them from `NSTableView` after that. http://take.ms/6r3IV

### Expected Results

I expect that my records will be updated and `NSTableView` will be reloaded to reflect my changes.

### Actual Results

My application crashes. http://take.ms/q6SWw

### Steps to Reproduce

What are steps we can follow to reproduce this issue?

### Code Sample

https://gist.github.com/msamoylov/27e1b6c9255b254f033f44d6de115d20

### Version of Realm and Tooling

```
Realm version: 2.0.0 (installed as the Dynamic Framework)

Xcode version: 8.0 (8A218a)

macOS version: 10.12
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash within Xcode? That should let you see a stack trace and log output that's not redacted.

Comment: @bdash here it is, but it's the same as the information above: http://take.ms/0PSEo

Comment: Type `bt` in Xcode's debugger console after the crash to see the full backtrace. Or disable Xcode's "Show only stack frames with debug symbols and between libraries" setting to see the full backtrace in Xcode's debug pane.

Comment: So the new stacktrace you've shared shows AppKit's code for dealing with uncaught Objective-C exceptions. That's useful as it means we now know there's an Objective-C exception being thrown! You can set [a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions being thrown](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) to tell you the point at which things are really going wrong. Note that the linked article sets a breakpoint on _all_ exceptions (both C++ and Objective-C), while you'll only want to break on Objective-C exceptions for this.

Comment: Just linking to the cross-post on GitHub so we can continue cross-posting the discussion and answers: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4147.

Comment: @bdash here you go http://take.ms/q6SWw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I wasn't handling notifications properly. So, I ended up rewriting my code in this way:

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift


class ExerciseListViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var exerciseTableView: NSTableView!

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var exercises = try! Realm().objects(Exercise.self).filter("preferred = false").sorted(byProperty: "priority")
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        exerciseTableView.dataSource = self
        exerciseTableView.delegate = self
        exerciseTableView.doubleAction = #selector(self.addPreferredExercises(_:))

        notificationToken = exercises.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let exerciseTableView = self?.exerciseTableView else { return }
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                exerciseTableView.reloadData()
                break
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, _):
                exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()
                exerciseTableView.insertRows(at: IndexSet(insertions), withAnimation: .slideDown)
                exerciseTableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(deletions), withAnimation: .effectFade)
                exerciseTableView.endUpdates()

                if self?.exercises.count == 0 {
                    self?.dismiss(nil)
                }

                break
            case .error(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
                break
            }
        }
    }


    deinit {
        notificationToken?.stop()
    }


    @IBAction func addPreferredExercises(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if exerciseTableView.selectedRowIndexes.isEmpty {
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = "Hint"
            alert.informativeText = "Please select at least one exercise from the list."
            alert.alertStyle = .informational
            alert.beginSheetModal(for: view.window!, completionHandler: nil)
        }

        try! realm.write {
            for index in exerciseTableView.selectedRowIndexes {
                if exercises.indices.contains(index) {
                    let exercise = exercises[index]
                    exercise.preferred = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ExerciseListViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return exercises.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return exercises.indices.contains(row) ? exercises[row].name : nil
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, toolTipFor cell: NSCell, rect: NSRectPointer, tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int, mouseLocation: NSPoint) -> String {
        let exercise = exercises[row]
        let comment = exercise.comment as String!

        return comment!
    }
}
```

It still doesn't work 100% correct with multiple selections, but at least it's not crashing the app anymore. For some reason `exerciseTableView.selectedRowIndexes` contains non-existing indexes.

Comment: Hello Michael. Any updates since? I have very similar code although I haven't yet figured out how to update rows when my NSTableView is sorted by a column or filtered. Perhaps you've made some progress and have implemented that.

Comment: hey @empedocle. No, I'm still using the above solution. Seems to be working just fine.

Comment: It looks to work well since I think your filter and sort order never changes. I have NSSortDescriptors sorting by any column and also filter by search, so the change indices don't match the view. Not sure if it's the best way, but I got so far modifications and insertions working by looking up .index(of: …) in the sorted/filtered list and then mapping to a new array.

Comment: I was thinking re-adding the notification after a change in filter or sort order might be the way, though didn't try it. If you ever need it, looks to be correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142827/how-do-i-work-with-realm-notification-if-result-is-updated-after-notification-is